# discord.js pagination embeds

Tags: javascript, pagination, discord.js

So basically I have an array of items : [ apple, banana , peach , pear , coconut , orange ... and so on ]

I want to display them in an embed but since embed has a character limit , I want to display only 10 elements per page and whenever the user reacts with arrow emojis - it will take them to the other page- so basically paginating an embed. But no matter how many ways I try , I cannot seem to do that- Help is very appreciated!

P.S - I deleted my codes out of frustration so I can't provide a code- well my code wouldn't be any help anyways-

Comment: Which part do you specifically need help on? Adding 10 items per embed or editing the embed once the user reacts with an arrow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the [discord.js-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-pagination) module for this. It allows you to provide an array of embeds and then it handles all the difficult stuff.

```js
const pagination = require('discord.js-pagination');

// array of the embeds to send
// The embeds cannot have footers as the module adds the page number here.
const pages = [
    new MessageEmbed().setTitle('1'),
    new MessageEmbed().setTitle('2'),
    new MessageEmbed().setTitle('3'),
]

// basic usage
pagination (msg, pages);
```

Comment: everyone keeps pasting this, but where do I actually call the code in the module.exports = {
    name: 'h', //.ping
    cooldown: 5,
    description: 'Current Release Schedule',
    execute(message) {
    },
};